# Django 1.8 deep reverse relationship lookup

Tags: django

I have three models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    idproduct=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    productname=models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
    product_state=models.BooleanField(default=True)


class ProductInventory(models.Model):
    idinventory=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    product_idproduct=models.ForeignKey(Product)
    storage_idstorage=models.ForeignKey(Storage)

class Sale(models.Model):
    idsale=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    sale_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    inventory_idinventory=models.ForeignKey(ProductInventory)
```

What I want to do is to get all the products that has been sold in this month, I have tried this:

```
thisdate=datetime.today()
products=Product.objects.filter(product_state=1,productinventory__sale__sale_date__month=thisdate.month).values('pk','productname','productinventory__sale__sale_date')
```

But first, it gives me "nested lookup is not supported" so I taked off the month filter, but after that it gives me a FieldError: `Cannot resolve keyword 'sale' into field`

How can I do this?

Comment: Where is your `Storage` model? Also, any reason you are following this particular naming convention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you querying from product? Why wouldn't you query from `Sale`?

```
Sale.objects.filter(sale_date__month=thisdate).filter(inventory_idinventory__product_idproduct__productstate=True).values('inventory_idinventory __product_idproduct__pk', 'inventory_idinventory __product_idproduct__ productname')
```

Also, your naming convention is really bad, I believe Henry H offered a cleanup solution, I would recommend it as well. If you cleaned that up you could make this look really nice with a custom manager method.

Comment: I didn't think in that, I'm going to try it from Sale.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
    state=models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Product_Inventory(models.Model):
    product=models.ForeignKey(Product)
    storage=models.ForeignKey(Storage)

class Sale(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    product_inventory=models.ForeignKey(Product_Inventory)
```

---

```
thisdate=datetime.today()
inventory=[]
products=[]

sales = Sale.objects.filter(date__month = thisdate.month)
for item in sales:
    inventory.append(Product_inventory.objects.filter(sale = item))
for product in inventory:
    products.append(Product.objects.filter(product_inventory = product))

print products
```

Something like this would work. I've taken liberty to clean up your model as it was difficult to read. IDs are automatically added to your models (as pk) so you don't necessarily have to add them here.

Comment: I have used the id's because it is related to a MySql database, and i must use that ID's, not Django's. And thankyou for the solution, I'm going to try it.

Comment: By default the name in the table automatically gets "_id" appended to the names of your primary keys which can be omitted completely from your models.